# How to check insert/update/delete counts per table/database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there any script that I can use to tell me the number of insert/update/delete happened on a table/database last hour, today, or so on?

Comment: Not directly but you can look at the documentation for sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats which tracks similar data at an index level, note1 to get the information for an hour you would need to store snapshot the data twice at the start and the end and then calculate the difference. Note2 There are database events which reset the counters - i.e. see the section - How the Counters in the Metadata Cache Are Reset

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

You can use Query Store...
Applies to: SQL Server (all supported versions) ,Azure SQL Database ,Azure SQL Managed

After enabling Query Store; The following query will show you your required stats...
SELECT Txt.query_text_id, Txt.query_sql_text, Pl.plan_id, Qry.*
FROM sys.query_store_plan AS Pl
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query AS Qry
ON Pl.query_id = Qry.query_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text AS Txt
ON Qry.query_text_id = Txt.query_text_id ;